# ICommand vs IValueConverter

Tags: wpf, prism

I am new to WPF. I am currently developing an application in WPF where I had to enable/disable a button based on a value from database. I found solutions on the net to do so using Command as well as Converters. So which one is a better solution and why?

Comment: `DataTriggers` can also be handy in this scenario, But `ICommand` is probably the best option if its just for buttons.

Comment: Commands will do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with buttons it would be best to use the command implementation , since it is built in 
and you can provide a command parameter for predicate , the converter is something you would need to 
write , instance and place in each place you would wan't to use it .

To summarize a command with CanExecute would be more reusable and maintainable .

Answer (score 0):

Since you're new to WPF, I truly recommend you start learning Rx Extensions and Reactive UI as well.
Reactive UI provides a Command Framework that can really help you in complex scenarios where your commands depend on many flags/conditions that can be computed through lambda functions and Observables.

If you want to create a complex Application you should definitely start learning MVVM. For a simple application use MVVM Light. For more complex WPF applications you can go for Reactive UI or Microsoft PRISM.

Have a look at [Reactive UI here](http://www.reactiveui.net/) . There's a few Command  examples in the Home page of Reactive UI but you can also get more samples in [here](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Samples/tree/master/ReactiveUI.Samples.Commands)

For instance you could declare an ICommand like this:

```
 DisplayCommand = new ReactiveCommand(this.WhenAny(x => x.Name, x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Value)));
```

Have a look at the documentation.

As mentioned previously, you should use a Command instead of a converter for this scenario.

In addition, if the events you want to listen for are other ones besides click then use the System.Interactive behaviors/actions as described [here](http://coreclr.wordpress.com/2011/01/05/using-interaction-triggers-in-mvvm/).